# Integral on a domain A

Tags: real-analysis

I have the domain $A=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3, x^2+y^2+z^2\le4 , x^2+y^2-2y\le0 \}$ and I want to calculate $\int_A |z|\, dx\, dy \,dz$.

$A$ is the intersection of a sphere and a cylindric on $R^3$ so can I use cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you can use cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: the result is ${5\pi}\over{2} $

Comment: It is correct...

Comment: @KittyL I don't know how to get this answer.  Below are my calculations.

\begin{align*}
  &2\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} zr \,\mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \\
  =& 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta} r \cdot \frac{4-r^2}{2} \,\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \\
  =& \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta} (4r-r^3) \,\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \\
  =& \int_{0}^{\pi} (8 \sin^2 \theta - 4 \sin^4 \theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
  =& 2\left( 8 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} - 4 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \pi \right) \\
  =& 5\pi
\end{align*}

Comment: 2(8.....). Why 2?

Comment: There should not be a $2$ at the second last step. Without that $2$, you should get the correct answer. The $2$ in the first step is because you integrate only the top half part by using $0$ to $\sqrt{4-r^2}$.

Comment: @KittyL Thank you for proofreading my answer.  It is a careless mistake.  I got it now